# How to sort imports alphabetically for TypeScript files automatically in WebStorm / PhpStorm?

Tags: typescript, phpstorm, webstorm, tslint, code-standards

I use tslint with default config `tslint:recommended` and I want to adapt as less rules as possible.

Certain rules enforce that [imports should be alphabetized](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/ordered-imports/):

```
src/core/task/TaskMockDecorator.ts[2, 1]: Import sources within a group must be alphabetized.
src/core/task/taskRunner.ts[1, 16]: Named imports must be alphabetized.
```

I don't want to sort the imports alphabetically by myself. Before I disable that linting: Can WebStorm / PhpStorm do that for me?

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution?

Comment: @denis No. It's still standing.

Comment: @Denis The new answer might help you out :)

Comment: This ESLint plugin can do the sorting via the `--fix` command to ESLint: [`eslint-plugin-import`](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to webstorm: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/tslint.html

> With WebStorm, you can fix some of the issues reported by TSLint > automatically.
>
> To fix a specific error, place the cursor at the highlighted code, press ⌥⏎, and then choose TSLint: fix current error from the pop-up menu.
> To fix all the issues detected in the file, choose TSLint: fix current file.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Posting almost just a link is not enough, please ensure your answer will be still useful if that link breaks down. E.g. quote the relevant parts from the linked page.

Answer (score 16):

As of [TSLint 4.0](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/2016/11/17/new-for-4.0.html), the ordered-imports rule features automatic fixing of violations. You can run it through the CLI with the `--fix` flag.

Comment: i found somewhere and also tested it works only for semicolon.. and for other we need to write custom rules..any suggestion  to make works more rules without writing custom rules

Comment: To also remove unused imports, we use and recommend [tslint-etc](https://github.com/cartant/tslint-etc) (since TSLint's option for this is deprecated).  The tslint-etc author has also been very quick (~1 hr) to push fixes for issues.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

In *WebStorm* and *Rider* there is default keymap action to *Optimize Imports*, under *CTRL+ALT+O*, I suppose that it exist in *PhpStorm* as well.

[image: Screenshot from JetBrains Rider settings with Optimize Imports keymap shown]